# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin"?

Tags: reactjs, api, http, react-native, react-redux

I used request in React to get data from api
but I'm getting this error :

> Failed to load
>   https://xxxx/api/yyyy?results=1000: Response
>   to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8000' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I enabled cross-origin resource sharing in my chrome but I face the same error

this is the route

```
Route::group(['middleware'=>'cors:api'],function(){
Route::get('/xxxx','yyyyController@yyyFunction');
});
```

and this is the cors middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
   {
       return $next($request)
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')

       ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Description')
       ->header('Connection', 'close')
       ->header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=2592000')
       //->header('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked')

       ;
   }
```

Comment: Its issue on server side. You have to allow Cross Origin Access in your api server. Otherwise it'll not work.

Comment: if you have already enabled it on server side, try installing chrome extension for CORS

Comment: @HarshVardhan I installed it but i get same error

Answer (score 1):

If you call an API from browser but this endpoint has not been defined the CORS, Browser will block the request and show the error like in your question. You can refer this doc to learn more about [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)

Answer (score 1):

Try this is work for me.

***reactjs use axios

```
const data = { 'id': 'xx', 'article': 'dd' };
const url = 'http://localhost:8080/path'
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  data: qs.stringify(data),
  url,
};
axios(options)
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Hope for help.